# If I pass a component as a prop, when does it get rendered?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React application. In my app, I generally want my view components to not import other react components directly. Rather, I want a view's parent container component to take care of gathering dependencies and injecting them to the view via props.

This usually looks like this:

```
// Container.js

import SomeOtherComponent from '/somewhere'
import View from './View'

class Container extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <View
               component={<SomeOtherComponent/>}
            />
        )
    }
}

// View.js
const View = props => (
    <div>
        {props.component}
    </div>
)
```

But note how SomeOtherComponent appears to be instantiated when passed as a prop to View.

Does this mean SomeOtherComponent is instantiated (therefore going through all its relevant lifecycle methods) before View is?

Or is SomeOtherComponent only instantiated when View is instantiated and View's render method is called?

Comment: Don't pass the component with `</>` around it. That's what is causing the instantiation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "instantiated". `<SomeOtherComponent/>` gets transpiled to `React.createElement(SomeOtherComponent, null)`, so if instantiated means calling React.createElement, then it will happen during Container's render.

However, i don't think that's a very meaningful thing to pay attention to. All that React.createElement does is produce a small object describing what to render. That object will be roughly like this (i've omitted some stuff):

```
{
  type: SomeOtherComponent,
  props: null,
  key: null,
  ref: null,
}
```

The mere act of creating these objects does not cause any components to be mounted or go through the lifecycles. Instead, they must be returned by a render function. More than that, in your case, the Container isn't returning it as a thing to render, but as a prop to pass. So after Container calls render, react will see that it's supposed to mount a View. It does so, passing in the object from above as a prop. This newly-mounted view then renders, and as part of that, it finally returns the object. Only at this point does react mount that component.

So if "instantiated" means "mounted", then it will begin mounting the Container first, then the View, then the SomeOtherComponent. SomeOtherComponent finishes mounting first, then View finishes, then Container finishes.

Comment: is it better to pass "created" components as props or not created (that is `<View
               component={SomeOtherComponent} />`) so that `SomeOtherComponent` is actually created inside `View`?

Answer (score 1):

The `constructor` and `render` methods run in the correct order. The `componentDidMount` runs as you describe it.

See the logs in https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-benz-c6hlb

Answer (score 0):

It will be instantiated when you will show the corresponding View. This happends because conponent reacts to rendering in DOM, not to just importing it.
In the next example if you remove "{component}" from render method of App the NotUsedComponent wont be initialized and console.log inside componentDidMount wont be called.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";


class NotUsedComponent extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("NotUsedComponent is mounted");
  }
  render() {
    return <div />;
  }
}


function App() {
  const component = <NotUsedComponent />;

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      {component}
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

So no render - no init.